# Macro to convert equations into images in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am trying to preapre a macro that would convert all equations in a PowerPoint2010 presentation into images while retaining the position and animation effect/order.

Based on the tip provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057432/convert-all-worksheet-objects-to-images-in-powerpoint) (thanks to Steve Rindsberg), I have modified the script as below:

```
    Sub ConvertAllShapesToPic()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoTextBox, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                Case Else
            End Select
        Next
    Next

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Resume Next

End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    Dim oNewSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent
    oSh.Copy
    Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)
    oSh.PickupAnimation
    oNewSh.ApplyAnimation
    With oNewSh
        .Left = oSh.Left
        .Top = oSh.Top
        Do
            .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
        Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
        .AnimationSettings.AnimationOrder = oSh.AnimationSettings.AnimationOrder
    End With
    oSh.Delete

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Problems with this script:

1. ALL the equations are not getting converted into images.
2. Some text boxes with no equations are losing their internal anim effects (such as displaying the second bulleted text On Click).

My reason for preparing this script is because when I convert PowerPoint 2010 into Articulate presentations, the equations are not getting rendered properly since Articulate 09 does not fully support PPT2010 equations.

I have more than 100 PPTs, with equations on nearly all slides. Without a programmatic method, the only option would be to convert all the equations manually and reapply the anim effects!

Appreciate any help that you can offer :-)

Thanks!

Comment: See below for a likely answer to the "not getting converted" problem.  Not sure I follow the animation effects problem though.  More detail please?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the first problem, my bad:

For this:

```
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoTextBox, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                Case Else
            End Select
        Next
Next
```

Substitute:

```
Dim x as long 

For x = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count to 1 Step -1
        Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoTextBox, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                Case Else
            End Select
        Next
Next
```

I probably only tested slides with one equation per slide when I wrote this originally.  When you step through a collection and possible delete members, you need to step through backwards, else the indexing gets messed up when you delete a member.

Comment: Hi Steve! Really nice of you to have read my question and for your help :-) Your script works like a charm. However, I find that equations which are nested inside a group are not getting converted. Any ideas how we could solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is also weird is that some text-boxes are getting converted into images while others are not. Is there any way to target only text-boxes with equations? I've tried msoTextBox, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject, msoPlaceholder, msoOLEControlObject, msoAutoShape; but none of them convert every equation. I'd like to provide a sample PPT but it appears that attachments are not allowed here.

Comment: You'd need to add a test to see if the current shape is of type msoGroup and if so, look at each item in the shape's .GroupItems collection to see if IT meets the test for the type of shapes you want to convert to equations.  Since there may also be groups within groups, and anon, you'll probably want to write it as a recursive routine.  As to your second comment, I don't have a good answer, but if you want to post a sample file someplace (dropbox, your site, wherever) I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: This is certainly getting out of my league! :-) I will just do the changes manually and hope that the next version of Articulate would resolve this issue. Thanks a million for taking time to help me, Steve! Deeply grateful :-)

Comment: No probablem, Prasad.  I've added another bit of code in a second answer ... a kind of demo of how recursion would work in this case. It sounds complicated and looks as though it's not even possible ... but it works. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        DoSomethingToEachShape oSh
    Next

End Sub

Sub DoSomethingToEachShape(oSh As Shape)
    Dim x As Long
    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For x = 1 To oSh.GroupItems.Count
            DoSomethingToEachShape oSh.GroupItems(x)
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print oSh.Name
    End If
End Sub
```