# Powerpoint 2010 : change MS Equation 3 objects font color OR background programmatically

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

Thanks to this question ( [Macro to convert equations into images in Powerpoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393669/macro-to-convert-equations-into-images-in-powerpoint-2010) ) I have some VBS code that loops through equations in a ppt and converts them to images.
However I'm interested in **changing the font color of such equations to black OR the whole background of each equation to black**. What I miss is the command to set the font color to black.

I'm starting with low contrast slides and I'm turning them into black on white. All normal text can be changed quickly via color schemes, but equation objects, whose fonts are currently pale yellow, are somehow "locked". To make them visible on a white background I have to either make those fonts black, or turn the background of each equation black. The first option would be preferable, since reading black on white it's easier for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by:

1. batch changing the extension of each presentation to zip with [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php);
2. batch extracting each zip to a unique folder with WinRAR;
3. locating each equation object (*.emf files) in all the "media" folders of said extracted zips with XYplorer;
4. batch converting them to *.eps with Adobe Illustrator, modifying all the colors to black;
5. rezipping each folder and resetting the extension back to pptx.