# "Error -2147188160 (80048240) Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request." when trying to convert objects to images in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm a new stackoverflow user so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but I'm trying to post a question on a [previously given solution by Steve Rindsberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057432/convert-all-worksheet-objects-to-images-in-powerpoint). I don't have enough reputation to comment, and there doesn't appear to be a way to message another user directly, so I'm posting a new question here.

I can't seem to get the code below to work. I'm using PowerPoint O365 Version 1901 and I have two type of shapes I'm trying to convert, msoChart and msoLinkedOLEObject (some Excel worksheets). I originally changed ppPasteEnhancedMetafile to ppPastePNG because I want PNG's, but it fails with either.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ConvertAllShapesToPic()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                Case msoPlaceholder
                    If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoEmbeddedOLEObject _
                        Or oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoLinkedOLEObject _
                        Or oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoChart _
                        Then
                        ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                    End If
                Case Else

            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    Dim oNewSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent
    oSh.Copy
    Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1)

    With oNewSh
        .Left = oSh.Left
        .Top = oSh.Top
        Do
            .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
        Loop Until .ZOrderPosition < oSh.ZOrderPosition
    End With

    oSh.Delete

End Sub
```

I noticed if I run ConvertAllShapesToPic from an link/action in Slide Show mode, it doesn't complete and fails silently. If I add a Command Button (ActiveX control) and run it from there I get the following:

Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)':

Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request.  The specified data type is unavailable.

It's failing on Set oNewSh = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1). After the error, if I go back to the slide and Ctrl-V I get the image, so I know it's working up to that point.

I've tried various solutions I found online for this such as adding DoEvents or ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate after the copy, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is not an uncommon problem. I don't think anyone has ever tied it to a specific version or file but it appears to be a timing issue. I don't have time to do the lookup right now, but I recall having seen solutions to this here on StackOverflow. Might want to see if you can turn up other posts about this problem.

Comment: Okay thanks Steve. I'll keep digging

Answer (score 0):

I found some other code to convert the charts and then I break links on the worksheets which automatically turns them in to images.

One thing I figured out was you must be out of slide show mode to break msoLinkedOLEObject links. I'm not 100% sure why... but this is the code that works for me:

```
Sub DoStuff()

    Call LinkedGraphsToPictures
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
    Call BreakAllLinks

End Sub


Sub LinkedGraphsToPictures()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim pic As Shape
    Dim shp_left As Double
    Dim shp_top As Double

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes

            If shp.Type = msoChart Then
                'Retrieve current positioning
                shp_left = shp.Left
                shp_top = shp.Top

                'Copy/Paste as Picture
                shp.Copy
                DoEvents
                sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePNG

                Set pic = sld.Shapes(sld.Shapes.Count)

                'Delete Linked Shape
                shp.Delete

                'Reposition newly pasted picture
                pic.Left = shp_left
                pic.Top = shp_top
            End If

        Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub


Sub BreakAllLinks()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub
```